# Thread or services

Tags: android

I'm confused between thread and service on android.
If I have to download some file from the server. It may be multiple files at a time.
What should I choose in this situation, thread or services?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Doing Stuff in a [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) does not make it run in the background. You have to create a Thread in your service as well to wait for the download to complete.

If you are using a thread that is local to an activity you will have problems with leaving the activity, sending it to the background or an interruption because of an incoming call etc. This may cause your app to be killed by the OS to free up memory. In this case your thread is lost and may not get restarted and make your app crash.

If you create a service you are not as likely to be killed then just a thread and you can specify the OS to restart the service after it gets killed by the OS. This makes the service a more secure choice for very long downloads. I use a service in one of my apps to download a 20 mb file and in this service create a thread that does the downloading.

A service only helps you to encapsulate the download and decouples it from the activity and gives you another state in the OS that will prevent the thread from just disappear because of low memory.

Comment: thanks for your answer!
So i should help a service that store a thread, don't i ?

Comment: Additionally, there are five levels in the Android process importance hierarchy. And like @Janusz said, "using thread or service" can affect the importance of its process. "Because a process running a service is ranked higher than a process with background activities, an activity that initiates a long-running operation might do well to start a service for that operation, rather than simply create a worker thread—particularly if the operation will likely outlast the activity."

Comment: "For example, an activity that's uploading a picture to a web site should start a service to perform the upload so that the upload can continue in the background even if the user leaves the activity." from http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html

Answer (score 18):

> What i should choose in this situation thread or services?

It's not an "or". It's an "and". You use a background thread *and* a service.

A service is "in the background" from a UI standpoint, in that it has no UI. A service is not automatically "in the background" from a threading standpoint, in that `onCreate()`, `onDestroy()`, `onStart()`, and `onBind()` are all called on the main application thread, the same thread shared by all the activities of this application. Anything long-running, like a download, needs to be done outside of the main application thread, such as using an `AsyncTask`.

If your downloads need to go on even if the activity that triggered them is destroyed, you need to use a service, with the service using an `AsyncTask` or background thread to complete the download. Even better is to use an `IntentService`, which combines a regular service with a background thread.

Comment: that's really well explained. Very easy to understand.

Comment: thanks for your answer!
So i should help a service that store a thread, don't i ?

Answer (score 0):

Thread is fine for doing a task in background for one application. You would want to use a service if you needed this for multiple applications.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to provide an interface for other Apps to communicate with your downloading Activity: service.
If the download should just run in the background to allow the user to interact with the UI.

Answer (score 0):

your question is already in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html). Check the right column.