# What does the common advice "start a thread in a service" even mean?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, service

Service callbacks run on the main thread just like activities' (unless otherwise specified). I seem to stumble upon lots of advice here on SO that goes something like "start a thread in a service [to do work in the background]". That doesn't make sense to me. What does it matter if I start a thread from activity code compared to service code, just as long as there exists a started service component in the application process?

If the answer is what I think (that it doesn't matter) then it's a shame that people give the impression that a service object needs to be somehow related to the background thread.

Comment: If no reason is given for down votes then my next question just might look like this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not matter where you actually start a thread if the lifetime of that thread is reflected via your app process state: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#Lifecycle

Android does not care if there is a `Thread` running or not. Threads just run even when your app is considered an empty process "that doesn't hold any active application components." Don't abuse that, since users don't want that apps are secretly active although they look dead.

If you want (and you should) that Android does not kill you randomly although your threads are not done you have to make sure that you keep e.g. a `Service` in started state.

Creating a thread from *within* a `Service` (or just using `IntentService`) will primarily result in better, simpler & cleaner code. For example because a `Service` has a `Context` and you can't leak your `Activity` from there. You also get free callbacks from the system.

And leaks via threads are extremely easy.

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        SystemClock.sleep(Long.MAX_VALUE);
    }
}).start();
```

Will leak your activity if you just put it in e.g. `onCreate` because the anonymous inner `Runnable` keeps a reference to your `Activity` and will not release it until the thread stops running and is itself garbage collected.

In case you really know what you are doing, feel free to start threads in Activities and sync their lifecycle manually to some empty `Service`. I would not recommend it because it's unlikely to be less work to do that correctly.

Comment: This is very helpful, you cleared my doubts. And you added some hidden pitfalls of not doing it the recommended way, which is exactly the thing I can't ask about specifically but still need to know. Even if I end up doing it the recommended way I'll know what's happening and what my options are.

Answer (score 3):

The term "background" can be misleading when it comes to `Services` as it can have two meanings. `Services` are used, simplistically talking, to run tasks even if there is no `Activity` of your application running. To clarify, think of a music player; you want the music to still play even if the `Activity` is not running. That is the definition of background that doesn't have to do with `Threads`; you are running a portion of your application in the background because you do not have any visible component of your app on the screen (maybe some `Notification` but no full screen UI).

Now, lets say you want to download some data from the internet. As you might know, you cannot perform long running tasks in the UI `Thread` (as of API 11+ you will get a `NetworkOnMainThreadException`), so you need to use a background `Thread`. Let's say you do not want to use an `AsyncTask` to download the content because a `Service` is better suited for your needs. In this case, you will have to start the `Service` on a background `Thread`. That is the second meaning of background, which basically means creating a new `Thread`. Android provides a class that does exactly this; `IntentService`. It is a `Service` that runs on a background `Thread` and that it finishes itself when the given task is done.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and effort. I agree with you up until "you will have to start the Service on a background thread". Why would I have to do that? What does that accomplish? Starting a service is not expensive and can easily be done on the main thread without any impact on responsiveness, as far as I know. I also don't see where in the documentation it says that the `IntentService` callbacks run in a different thread than the main thread, if that's where it was started. The only thing that is obvious is that its `onHandleIntent()` will be called on another thread.

Comment: Think of the second case. Long running tasks have to run on a separate `Thread`. For example, you really do not know how long a network call will take, so if you didn't have it running on a background `Thread` the UI will be non responsive all that time. It is probably not a good idea to bind an `IntentService` therefore, no callbacks come into play. You should probably use a `LocalBroadcastManager` to deliver results to the rest of your app. In that way your `Service` is as loosely coupled as possible to your `Activity`

Comment: I think we are talking about entirely different things. I'm not interested in the use cases for worker threads. I'm interested in if it matters from where in my code my thread is started. I'm interested in this because it has been implied in other answers that "you should start a thread **in** a service". Contrast this with "you should start a service. Then create a new thread [from anywhere]".

Comment: Can you please provide a link to an answer that says that? You can start a `Thread` from where you feel it is needed. No specific need to start it on a `Service`

Comment: Sure, here's one http://stackoverflow.com/a/3520868/220820. I see it frequently and thought there might be something to it. The covert way in which `Handler` and `Looper` interacts with threads made me doubt my knowledge of what is actually happening behind the scenes since I'm new to Android (but not to Java).

Comment: Have you seen the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3520874/2029566) just below that one?

Comment: No, I hadn't read it. However it doesn't tell me anything that I didn't already know. It basically repeats the same thing as the answers that I have an issue with: "you need to use a service, with **the service using an [...] background thread**". (Once again implying that there is a connection between the thread and the service it was started from)

Comment: I hope you'll excuse if I was unclear in my question, thanks again for your time.